# Virtual webcam with MJPEG output

Tags: video, software-recommendation, codec, camera

I have an very specific situation maybe someone can help with.

**The short story/question:**

Is there a virtual webcam software that can output as a virtual webcam in the **motion JPEG (MJPEG) format**? RTSP output will not work.

**The long story/questions:**

I'm trying to get a nursing simulation software (Laerdal LLEAP / Session Viewer) to record a webcam using it's integrated recording, however it only supports web cameras that support stop motion JPEG. IP Cameras will not work with the software - it has to be a webcam. There's a few logitech webcams that do support this, however I need to use a Vadeo PTZ camera we already have that outputs HDMI. I've been able to successfully use an HDMI capture card (the Epiphan AV.io) to get the PTZ camera on the computer as a webcam, however the capture card does not produce an output that the simulation software accepts. It will not detect the webcam. I've tried other virtual webcams (Wirecast, iSpy, ManyCam, VidBlaster, etc.), but they all seem to output RTSP and not MJPEG. All of these work great in other webcam applications (Skype, etc.), but not on the simulation software. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can make this work or trick this simulation software into detecting the webcam. It seems to be very picky. Buying a compatible logitech webcam that supports stop motion JPEG is not an option. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Here is a note from the software developer about the web cam required:**

The new release of Session Viewer has new technology for video capture. To be able to work on slower computers, Session Viewer now uses stop motion JPEG technology to create a video from a series of JPEG images. Not all web cameras can support stop motion JPEG. This includes many of the cameras previously distributed by Laerdal. If you currently use a web cam as a means to record simulations, you may need to upgrade to a newer model. Laerdal will be selling the Logitech c930e (part number 400-96050) as the preferred model. Logitech models c920 and c920-c are also supported.

Comment: If your webcam shows up as a directshow input, then ffmpeg can output to a mjpeg pipe.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how I could achieve this with ffmpeg? I don't have any experience with ffmpeg. Reading documentation on it now though.